# How to fix alignment of colors in apexchart after applying gradient fill with axistype-datetime with multiple x-axis labels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

In my code, I have applied a colorstop in a line chart using the fill gradient option. I have set the x-axis type as datetime. The Colorstop works correctly when there are a small number of labels. However, when there are 5 or 7 labels, such as one label per week day, the applied colors in the chart do not match the data. Even though everything else is correct, the alignment of colors is mismatched. I resolved this issue by converting the x-axis type to category, but in my case, it should remain as datetime.

In code i have used range value 100,220,450 and green,red,yellow color, 0 t0 100 values color should by green,100 to 220 color should be yellow and 220 to 450 color should be red but due to many x-axis lable graph get crushed and alignment of color showing mismatched in x-axis type datetime

This is my sample code add for your reference [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-hoover-rifgty?file=/src/App.js)

sample image added:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpwnA.png
[linechart][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you interpolate the gradient by the index of the points, but you should interpolate it by the x distance, which is the date of the current point. Your approach only works if the points are equidistant in time, but that's not the case with your data.

A simple solution for your code is to compute the UNIX timestamp for each point `x` coordinate (date), by calling the [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) function. Your dates are almost in ISO 8601 format, except for some whitespaces that can be eliminated:

```js
const tStart = Date.parse(JsonData?.[0]?.x?.replace(/\s/g, "")),
    tEnd = Date.parse(JsonData?.[JsonData?.length - 1]?.x?.replace(/\s/g, "")),
    dt = tEnd - tStart;

const colorStops = JsonData.map((e, index) => {
    let color = "black";
    for (let j = 0; j < rangeValue?.length; j++) {
        if (e.y <= rangeValue[j].Range_End_Value) {
            color = rangeValue[j].Range_color;
            break;
        }
    }
    const t = Date.parse(e.x.replace(/\s/g, ""));
    
    return {
        offset: ((t - tStart) / dt) * 100,
        color,
        opacity: 0.5
    };
});
```

Here's a [codesandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-merkle-6puggj?file=/src/App.js) of yours with that change.

---

An alternative solution for your problem is to use a [vertical gradient](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/fill/). The only difficulty is that it starts from the top of the chart space. You also have to set (or compute) the maximum and minimum values of y axis.

If one sets the maximum value at

```js
const maxY = 450;
```

(assuming minimum at zero) for the two color breaks at 220 from red to yellow and at 100 from yellow to green (we have to think it top-down), the color stops should be:

```js
colorStops: [
    {
        offset: (1 - 220 / maxY) * 100,
        color: "red",
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    {
        offset: (1 - 220 / maxY) * 100,
        color: "yellow",
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    {
        offset: (1 - 100 / maxY) * 100,
        color: "yellow",
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    {
        offset: (1 - 100 / maxY) * 100,
        color: "green",
        opacity: 0.5
    }
]
```

which I hardcoded for brevity, but can be computed from a changeable data structure, like before.

Here's the [codesandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wood-g9by81?file=/src/App.js:1211-1763) that implements that variant.

Comment: Thanks for the code you shared, as it is effectively generating the desired graphs. However, I noticed a small discrepancy when zooming in on the graph, particularly when the y-axis range is relatively small, such as between 0 and 5. In these cases, there appears to be a slight mismatch in the colors used to represent different data points on the graph. This issue seems to be specifically related to situations where the y-axis values are lower in magnitude   
i have added the update code  
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-hoover-rifgty?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: If you use the horizontal gradient, indeed, it won't be perfect. I actually did a much more elaborate version the other day that registered only the color changes and set color stops on those segments by interpolation, but it still wasn't great, it actually worked ok only for a line width of 1. With a wider line on the almost vertical lines it unavoidably has parts that are at the wrong x for the targeted y. I didn't posted, since it wasn't a significant improvement over your variant, but you can check it out in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-bouman-v4gnbd)

Comment: Simply put, the gradient method is not an ideal method to color segments accurately when there are many points and abrupt variations. If the vertical gradient version is not convenient to your case I think you should explore other libraries that allow you to set the color for each segment directly.

Comment: even Vertical gradient  also i have tried still not working as expected. i have updated jsondata in  code i have provided . please look into that if possible provide any possible solution 
[Codesandbox-](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-forest-dzoqlt?file=/src/App.js) here i updated Jsondata that give error 
You can zoom and see the chart it look mismatched color difference

Comment: Can you please let me know why the vertical gradient version e.g., the one in this [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wood-g9by81?file=/src/App.js:1211-1763) is not good for your purposes? Because I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are 
trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, it worked for me when i dynamically used to generate the colorstop colors and thanks for the help